# Error:(66, 30) error: package PhoneAuthProvider does not exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Error:(66, 30) error: package PhoneAuthProvider does not exist

This is my app build.gradle 
P.S multidex enabled is true

Why this error happens?

---

---

---

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

// this line must be included to integrate with Firebase
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.5.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.2.0'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.1'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.theneura:android-sdk:+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
```

Instead of :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

the `phone authentication` was released with Firebase Android SDK v11 you need to update your auth module to `11.0.2` instead of `10.2.0`